# CSS for making an image responsive both to width and visible height of the containing element

Tags: html, css

I need the image to take the entire width of the container unless the resulting height is bigger then the available container's viewport height.

Basically I want the image to be responsive but also that it should still fit the screen. If it doesn't fit the screen it should be scaled down, horizontally centered, and preferably added with black tiles on its sides.

Currently, my CSS class looks like this:

```
.img-responsive{
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

I've tried to play around with max-height on the image, or on a dedicated container, nothing seemed to do the trick by pure CSS.

**Clarifications:**

1. I don't know the images dimensions in advance so can't just put them in a container with a preset size.
2. Basically, my goal is for the images to be always fully visible on the screen (if you scroll to the image) and take up the largest possible surface.

**Here's a more detailed example:**

Let's say I have scrollable container with a lot of content. The container takes up the entire viewport width (let's say its 500px) and the available visible height of the container is the entire viewport height minus a navbar height (let's say 1000px).

I can't know in advance what's the container's visible dimensions as it can always change.

Inside the container there's whatever, text, images, etc.

Now, for a given image, here are possible scenarios:

- If the image is 500x800, it should be presented as is, as it takes up the entire available width, and height is no bigger then the container's visible height.
- If the image is 500x2000, it should be scaled down to 250x1000 
  and horizontally centered. This will take up the entire visible container's height, and keep the image's aspect ratio
- If the image is 250x300, it should be scaled up to 500x600, taking up the entire available width
- If the image is 200x500, it should be scaled up to 400x1000, taking up the entire available height
- If the image is 1000x1000, it should be scaled down to 500x500, taking up the entire available width

[Here's a JSFiddle explaining the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/kqx1Lxrp/3/)

Comment: `.img-responsive{ display: block; margin: 0 auto; 
width: auto; min-height: 100vh; }`

Comment: Setting both `min-width` and `max-width` to `100%` is essentially the same thing as just setting the width to 100%.

Comment: @Scott, you're right, stupid mistake. just changed it to width 100%.

Answer (score 4):

I would advise against using the IMG tag for this. Rather use a div tag and then use background image properties. Here is the code for this, set the container size to whatever you like:

```
<div id="container"></div>

<style>
width: 500px;
height: 500px;
background-image: url('your url');
background-size: contain;

</style>
```

`background-size: contain` is what is best for this. It scales the image to the largest the image can be within the div without making it larger than its native size. Hope this helps

EDIT:
Forgot to add that if you want it to be in the center of the container, so that when the image doesnt fit the full size of the container there is the white space around it, you use the css code `background-position: center center;`

Comment: This assumes I know something about the image dimensions which I don't...

Comment: I can't limit the size of the suggested container as I don't know the image's dimensions in advance. The suggested container needs to take up the entire available width, but the height of the container needs to be maximized to the natural image height and limited to the containing element visible height.

Comment: how do you not know the images dimensions? what image are you using? a bit confused here

Comment: for the container, you make it the size you need (not the size of the image, but the size of the page or whatever). Then the image will auto size using `background-size: contain` to be as large as it possibly can without exceeding its native size.

Comment: I use images from random sources, have no info on the image prior to loading. Re the container size - I can have its width be set to 100% but its height is tricky, you can have a look at the example i sent...

Answer (score 0):

Mostly what you need is to give `img` elements two properties `{max-width:100%}` and `{height: auto}`

If you open the snippet below in full screen and resize your window **(Note: image sizes are randomly chosen)**

you will see how nice they play. They adhere to the max width and they don't overstretch themselves in any direction.

*I added some code in there just to make this easier to show*

like making giving images `{display:block}` and `{padding-bottom}`

```css
body {
  background: #131418;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}
body,
.image-container,
.image-container img,
.smalldiv {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.image-container img {
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
}
.smalldiv {
  /*for demnostration only */
  width: 600px;
  background: darkblue;
}
.smalldiv,
.image-container img {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<h3>Images will always keep their aspect ratio and they will always adhere to the width of their parent containers.</h3>
<hr>

<div class="image-container">
  <h4>This is what the image container looks like when it has the entire screen space</h4>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/650x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/950x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1250x3150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/550x650">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/650x950">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1250x1150">
</div>
<div class="smalldiv">
  <div class="image-container">
    <h4>This is what the image containing div looks when it's put inside a container smaller then the screen width</h4>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/650x150">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/950x150">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1250x3150">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/450x350">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/550x650">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/650x950">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/1250x1150">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

evilgenious448 answer comes really close, just that it **only works with background images**. What I have is:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0px;
    }

    .holder {
        background-image: url('image1.JPG');
        background-size: contain;
        background-position: center center;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="holder">
        <div class="inner">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not know how to size the inner div equally to the image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with code and everything:

You can drag around the page to *test*.

--- When the viewport is higher / taller than the image, the image's width is the width of the viewport disregarding viewport height. On the other hand, when the viewport is wider than the image, the image uses the viewports height, disregarding its with.

```css
#image {
  background-image: url(https://media.cntraveller.com/photos/611bedcd231ed5e8dfa34573/16:9/w_2580,c_limit/sennen-cove-beach-britain-conde-nast-traveller-20april18-rex.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

```html
<body id="body">
<div id="image" />
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `height: 100%` of the parent container (in my case its `img-holder`). And apply `text-align: center` to the parent. Like:

```
.img-holder {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  text-align: center;
}

.img-holder img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Have al look at the snippet below:

```css
.img-holder {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-holder">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x200" alt="">
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't do the trick. I can't limit the img-holder dimensions in advance as I don't know the image's dimensions.

Comment: @NirD. You need an outer width as to make your image act on it. Its values may be in percentages also.

Answer (score -1):

The best and the easiest way is to use vh and vw properties. vh when set to 100 takes up the complete Viewport Height and same goes with vw for width. Further, max height property may be added to stop image from stretching beyond its original dimensions.